# VBA Run time Error 1004, For loop copy and paste run time "Method 'Range of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba, loops, runtime-error

```
Sub TransposeShuffledFielders()
'
' TransposeShuffledFielders Macro
' Copy and Paste the Fielders from Fielding Matrix
'

'
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 11
    
        Sheets("Fielding Matrix").Select
        Range("H6:H14").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Result Matrix").Select
        Range("Bi").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next
        
End Sub
```

Can any one fix this error? When I debug, it is showing the error at `Range("Bi").Select`

Thanks and Regards
Bhanu Prakash

Comment: `Range("B" & i).Select`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I am not following the code.  It looks like you are copying the same data 10 times.

Comment: You can do this without the loop: `Sheets("Result Matrix").Range("B2:J11").Value = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Fielding Matrix").Range("H6:H14").Value)`

Comment: Thank you Scott Craner, I used the Range("B" & i).Select

Comment: Range("A" & i : "Q" & i).Select
Can you help me with this type of mismatch error?